# How do other words can you use for “the way something is written”?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms, phrasing

I was racking my brain when pressed with a discussion posting in math class the other day, and I was coming to answer someone’s question when I got stuck in a bind.

The question was pre-Calc, and I was answering a question pertaining to some difficult math formatting. The word for the way the math was written had gotten jumbled in my brain. So I ask anyone who can help on the interwebs for their aid.

Here’s the sentence for the actual discussion where I faded off.

“These ones are kinda meant to trip people up by design because of the ________. The way’s it written is supposed to trick you, but the underlying convention of the problem is very simple.”

I appreciate any help, and I’m open to clarification’s or help to anyone.

Thank Everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

trip people up by design because of the ________.

I cannot think of a specifically mathematical term for such a word but some that might work are as follows.

This trips people up by design because of the *phrasing* or *wording* of the question.

This is also the *presentation* of the problem.

A more mathematical term does occur to me. This might be the *notation*. the notation or symbols used to describe a math problem can certainly lead you in one direction over another.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! IT WAS NOTATION I THANK YOU GLADLY

Comment: SO glad to hit it for you. Do please state the problem with the notation. We are all curious.